# Error: com.xwray.groupie.GroupieViewHolder cannot be cast to com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.GroupieViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

My app crashes when I launch this particular activity "ChatroomActivity": Full error is;

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xwray.groupie.GroupieViewHolder cannot be cast to 
com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.GroupieViewHolder
at com.example.westderepostel.ChatFromItem.bind(ChatroomActivity.kt:40)
at com.xwray.groupie.Item.bind(Item.java:63)
at com.xwray.groupie.Item.bind(Item.java:49)
at com.xwray.groupie.GroupAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GroupAdapter.java:233)
at com.xwray.groupie.GroupAdapter.onBindViewHolder(GroupAdapter.java:20)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6 
012)
at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerV 
iew.java:6279)
at
```

Please help, what should I do?
I started having issues with what version of groupie to use...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you have 2 classes GroupieViewHolder in different packages. First of all check if you correct import the GroupieViewHolder.

Comment: This is my list of imports:

Comment: import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Adapter
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupAdapter
import com.xwray.groupie.GroupieAdapter
import com.xwray.groupie.Item
import android.view.ViewGroup
//import com.xwray.groupie.ViewHolder
import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.GroupieViewHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_chatroom.*

Comment: This is my gradle libraries: implementation "com.xwray:groupie:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.xwray:groupie-kotlin-android-extensions:2.9.0"

Comment: remove this import `import com.xwray.groupie.kotlinandroidextensions.GroupieViewHolder`

Comment: Okay, i just did that and now i receive an error on this line: val adapter = GroupAdapter<GroupieViewHolder>().

Comment: GroupieViewHolder is red and needs an import. Which should i use?

Comment: `import com.xwray.groupie.GroupieViewHolder` try this.

Comment: I just did that sir ; ]

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.github.lisawray.groupie:groupie:2.10.1'

use this dependancy For import GroupAdapter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).